# Change Project Namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I change the project namespace in Visual Studio?

The namespace is currently `WindowsFormsApplication16`, and I want the namespace to be `MyName`.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can change the default namespace:
-> `Project` -> `XXX Properties...`
On Application tab: Default namespace

Other than that:
`Ctrl-H`
*Find*: WindowsFormsApplication16
*Replace*: MyName

Comment: Instead of Find/Replace, you can also right click the namespace in code and Refactor->Rename.

Comment: my Default Namespace textbox in project properties is disabled. any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't forget App.xaml if using WPF!

Comment: You also have to change your startup object. -> Project -> Properties -> Startup object -> <NewNamespace>.Program

Comment: @user1151923 You can change it by opening up your project file (MyProject.csproj) in a text editor and changing it there!
<RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>

Comment: When I right-click the root namespace in my code and click "Rename", I get the error "You cannot rename this element." This is the case both before and after I rename the root namespace under Project -> Properties. Right Click -> Rename only works for namespaces OTHER than the root namespace. It seems to me that using Find/Replace is going to be necessary after renaming the root namespace. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 49):

Instead of Find & Replace, you can right click the namespace in code and `Refactor -> Rename.`

Thanks to @[Jimmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25071/jimmy) for this.

Comment: This is the easiest way

Comment: Isn't this Resharper only?

Comment: Doesn't change every single file you have with your old name in your project.

Comment: When I right-click the root namespace in my code and click "Rename", I get the error "You cannot rename this element." This is the case both before and after I rename the root namespace under Project -> Properties. Right Click -> Rename only works for namespaces OTHER than the root namespace. It seems to me that using Find/Replace is going to be necessary after renaming the root namespace. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is not resharper only. I just did it in VS2022.

Comment: In VS 2022, the quick action becomes "Change namespace to match folder structure" if you've also renamed your solution/project folder(s) name(s). It can be applied project or solution wide.

Answer (score 14):

In visual studio right-click on your project then select `Edit Project File` or open the .csproj file directly then inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tag write the following tag

```
<RootNamespace>YourNamespaceName</RootNamespace>
```

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that this works with Visual Studio for Mac, too.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is for a C# project and assuming that you want to change the default namespace, you need to go to Project Properties, Application tab, and specify "Default Namespace".

Default namespace is the namespace that Visual studio sets when you create a new class. Next time you do Right Click > Add > Class it would use the namespace you specified in the above step.

Comment: Although this solution is better that what I found in compare to above one and yes after adding a new class I can see my new namespace in generated file but on right panel (Solution Explorer) still I can see the old name. any idea?    so I had to rename it directly in solution panel. Is that it?

Answer (score 4):

Just right click on the name you want to change (this could be namespace or whatever else) and select **Refactor->Rename...**

Enter new name, leave location as [Global Namespace], check preview if you want and you're done!

Answer (score 4):

"Default Namespace textbox in project properties is disabled"
Same with me (VS 2010).
I edited the project file ("xxx.csproj") and tweaked the  item. That changed the default namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Right click properties, Application tab, then see the assembly name and default namespace

Answer (score 1):

**First)**

1. Goto menu: **Project** -> **WindowsFormsApplication16 Properties**/
2. write  *MyName* in **Assembly name** and **Default namespace** textbox, then save.

**Second)**

1. open one old **.cs** file ( a *class* or a *form*)
2. right click on  ***WindowsFormsApplication16*** in front of *namespace*, goto ***Refactor -> Rename*** .
3. write *MyName* in **New name** textbox, in Rename Message Box.
4. press **Ok**, then **Apply**