# how to change namespace of entire project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm modifying demo application from this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

I need to update all files to use my namespace, for example now file located here:

```
MySolution\MyApp\DemoApp\ViewModel\MainWindowViewModel.cs
```

is using such namespace:

```
namespace DemoApp.ViewModel
{
/// <summary>
/// The ViewModel for the application's main window.
/// </summary>
public class MainWindowViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
```

I need to move file here (remove DemoApp folder):

```
MySolution\MyApp\ViewModel\MainWindowViewModel.cs
```

and also to use right namespace:

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
....
```

how to do that in visual studio 2010?

**Update** ok here is possible duplicate [Change Project Namespace in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871314/visual-studio-change-project-namespace) Now I know how to change the namespace of the project, but how to move files on the file system? (get rid of "DemoApp" folder)

Comment: Just as an FYI, you don't necessarily need the namespaces to match the folder structure in .NET, it's not required.

Comment: As james said, it's not required.. but I would question why someone didn't "finish the job" on an app I needed to work on.

Comment: Regarding moving files.. Um, cut/paste and drag/drop usually works within visual studio solution manager..  or even just rename folder or delete. depending on what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I imagine a simple Replace in Files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) will just about do the trick; simply replace `namespace DemoApp` with `namespace MyApp`. After that, build the solution and look for compile errors for unknown identifiers. Anything that fully qualified `DemoApp` will need to be changed to `MyApp`.

Comment: Important; change the default-namespace in project-properties too; this controls the namespace for things like resx

Comment: I have a couple of XAML files that represent WPF windows, so this won't work for me.

Comment: You should also run a Replace on any `using` statements to change from `using DemoApp` to `using Myapp`.

Comment: also rename <add namespace="OldNameSpace" /> in all of the web.config files in the views folder

Comment: @Pieter You should be able to do replace all for the entire application, followed by an update in the properties as Marc suggests, then close the solution and open it again otherwise VS has unexplainable behaviour with some auto completion.

Comment: I followed Adam's and Marc's steps, but in order to get rid of the `BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types` compiler error still present in several code behind files, I had to go to each corresponding ASPX file and re-save it, no changes necessary. This caused it to recompile using the updated namespace.

Comment: This is a very tedious way of going about it. There are much better ways using refactoring tools.

Answer (score 179):

Go to someplace the namespace is declared in one of your files.  Put the cursor on the part of the namespace you want to change, and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.  This should rename the namespace in every file.  At least, it worked in my little demo project I created to test this answer!

Depending on your VS version, the shortcut might also be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: by some reason doesn't work for me. I press F2 and nothing happen.

Comment: @javapowered, then your hotkey has been customized.  Look in VS options for yours.  Today mine is CTRL-R CTRL-R.

Comment: Note: Though I still prefer this method, it [understandably] failed to replace references in views and in the web.config file contained in the Views/ directory. Just watch for those.

Comment: For a version that shouldn't be dependent on hotkey changes, just right click the namespace name and choose rename.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if you want the new name to include a `.` character.

Comment: But Changing namespace from ex   ProductName to Company.ProductName  will not work with refracting

Comment: For namespaces containing . use this vs tool https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.FixNamespace

Comment: @Milen No, F2 is the default shortcut, and I wrote this answer before ever trying Resharper.  As for Ctrl+R,Ctrl+R, that's the [default keyboard shortcut for `Refactor.Rename` in VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx).  Your comment is completely incorrect.

Comment: @Amy Wow it looks like it is for VS2015. Well I guess we learn new things every day. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, For VS4Mac, it works great for first pass but seems you still have to go into the individual projects Options and update the General Namespace :)

Comment: In my ASP.NET MVC app doing this did not change the namespaces in the views so I had to do a find an replace for those, but still significantly less time than find and replace for all

Comment: Worth being aware that this will change the namespace through all projects in a solution, which you may not want

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 39):

Just right click the solution, go to properties, change "default namespace" under 'Application' section.

[image]

Comment: Does it changes namespace in existing files?

Comment: Nope, it will not.

Comment: You could find the namespace name and replace it with the "finder" in VS.
Also do the above to copy this over to new files.

Comment: Been looking for this for a while. You're time saver, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Visual studio 2022 has a new feature Sync Namespace.

You need to right click the project or solution in solution explorer.

[image]

If you have C# files which have been moved between folders and the namespaces are out of sync, this feature should come in handy to set the right namespace for each file based on the . format.

This will especially come in handy when you are performing a migration of a legacy code base.

**Reference**: https://nitinmanju.medium.com/de-clutter-namespaces-using-c-10-60822af79336

Comment: It doesn't work when I'm opening .NET classic projects. Not sure if it's a bug in VS2022.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or for complex namespace changes use this tool https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.FixNamespace

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> not the real solution.

You can use Resharper to change your all namespace definitions in your solution. This is the best way I tried before.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html

Comment: resharper requires full blown expensive desktop machine

Comment: @IvanG. well, many commercial projects require full blown expensive developers too, so a machine and a R# license isn't too costly in the grander scheme of things ;) If you need to check that this (or Adam or Amy's) method has worked correctly, you can look at [Find Code Issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Find_Code_Issues)

Comment: @StuartLC unfortunately the days of a dedicated workplace and big desktop have gone, I use a really powerful laptop for my development, and resharper practically kills it, so I wondn't recommend it to anyone who values time.

Comment: Guys you can just use for renaming for free you know :-) Install it activate free trial version, rename it and uninstall it if you want ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReSharper for namespace refactoring. It will give 30 days free trial. It will change namespace as per folder structure.

**Steps:**

1. Right click on the project/folder/files you want to refactor.
2. If you have installed ReSharper then you will get an option Refactor->Adjust Namespaces.... So click on this.

[image]

It will automatically change the name spaces of all the selected files.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the folder structure with a tool called BareGrep to ensure I have got all of the namespace changes. Its a free tool that will allow you to search over the files in a specified file structure.

Comment: file match REGEX: **(.exe)|(.dll)|(.cache)|(.pdb)**  _then invert the match_.   repeat this pattern to exclude other binaries et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything but I found a solution which really works. It creates independed solution with a new namespace name an so on.

1. In main form find namespace name -> right click -> Refactor -> Rename and select a new name. Check all boxes and click OK.
2. In the solution explorer rename solution name to a new name.
3. In the solution explorer rename project name to a new name.
4. Close VS and rename folder (in total commander for example) in the solution folder to a new name.
5. In .sln file rename old name to a new name.
6. Delete old .suo files (hidden)
7. Start VS and load project
8. Project -> properties -> change Assembly name and default namespace to a new name.

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late but for anyone looking to do it from now on, I hope this answer proves of some help. If you have `CodeRush Express` ([free version](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), and a 'must have') installed, it offers a simple way to change a project wide namespace. You just place your cursor on the namespace that you want to change and it shall display a `smart tag` (a little blue box) underneath `namespace` string. You can either click that box or press <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> keys to see the `Rename` option. Select it and then type in the new name for the project wide namespace, click `Apply` and select what places in your project you'd want it to change, in the new dialog and `OK` it. Done! :-)

Comment: In my experience CodeRush Express is not a 'must have' (personal opinion). It is handy for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to change namespace and the solution name I did as follows:
1) changed the namespace by selecting it and renaming it and I did the same with solution name
2) clicked on the light bulb and renamed all the instances of old namespace
3) removed all the projects from the solution
4) closed the visual studio
5) renamed all the projects in windows explorer
6) opened visual studio and added all the projects again
7) rename namespaces in all projects in their properties
8) removed bin folder (from all projects)
9) build the project again

That worked for me without any problems and my project had as well source control. All was fine after pushing those changes to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net is more to do, to get completely running under another namespace.

- Copy your source folder and rename it to your new project name.
- Open it and Replace all by Ctrl + H and be sure to include all [Replace everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imwx9.png)
- Press F2 on your Projectname and rename it to your new project name
- go to your project properties and adjust it, coz everything has gone and you need to make a new Debug Profile [Profile to Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r52g.png)
- All dependencies have now an exclamation mark - restart visual studio
- Clean your solution and Run it and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

When renaming a project, it's a simple process

- Rename your project
- Edit project properties to have new Default Namespace value
- Find/Replace all "namespace OLD" and "using OLD" statements in your solution
- Manually edit .sln file in text editor and replace your old project name in the directory structure with your new project name.
- Reload solution when VS prompts

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019 you can rename your namespace using the following steps

1. Place your cursor in the namespace name.
2. Press Ctrl+. to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu.
3. Select Change namespace to .
   For more refer to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/sync-namespace-and-folder-name?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying it out on `VS Code`, Use the typical `Rename` option, which will update all the namespace usages across, and if the project name is changed, you will have to go inside each `.csproj` and replace the new project name.

Don't forget to run `dotnet restore`, then only it will stop showing build issues.