# What does the "Sync Namespaces" feature do in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've recently noticed that Visual Studio 2022 has this feature to "Sync Namespaces".

[image]

Nothing seems to happen if I click on it. What is the intended purpose of this feature?

Comment: How to undo it? It screwed everything up. I have a lot of un-commited codes, it's impossible to undo by git.

Comment: @JoeHuang There does not appear to be a built-in "undo" function. My best advice is to commit often in the future, so that you can revert the changes using Git.

Comment: This post explains it pretty well https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583102/6527049

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It updates namespaces in your code to match folder structure.

For example, if you have a file Class1.cs in folder **Models** it changes the code namespace in Class1.cs to **Project.Models**.

Comment: seems it does not work in 17.1.0

Comment: This no longer works in VS 2022.  It only ever says No namespaces needed updating.  Even though many classes are in different folders.  It's broken.

Comment: @JasonStevenson works for me. I think is important that the solutions builds correctly first.

Comment: @Gioce90 of course the solution builds, it wasn't working on 17.1.6.  I haven't tested on the 17.3 preview yet.  Namespaces have nothing to do with file structure and a project building.

Comment: In my Solution, I have the option for my WPF .NET 7 executable, but not for the supporting Framework 4.7.2 DLLs. Anybody knows why ?

Comment: It seems to have problem in the latest versions, it always report "No namespaces needed updating." I just tested right now, I made an mismatch between namespace and folder structure, and it clearly don't work in VS 17.7.4.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  I have mismatched namespaces, build the project, then attempt to sync.  The result is a popup message "The solution does not contain the specified document"
Resharper 'Adjust Namespaces' works fine