# Copy references to class library ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a new class library in my project, and moved my `Models` folder to that. Now I need to get all the references like EntityFramework, DataAnnotations etc to my new class library.

Is there an easy way to do that(like copying them), without going into Nuget packages and downloading them one by one?

Comment: You only need to add reference to the new class library.  This is simple providing you have the new library in the same solution then every project can reference it.

Comment: @AliK i did that, but then i got hundred of errors saying how namespaces are missing... currently in the process of downloading them manually. Never had a problem with doing this before tho

Comment: Hey at least it worked...

Comment: You don't download namespaces. We can't know what the problem is if you don't give us accurate, detailed information.

Comment: do you need to copy Package References ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily copy all references from one project to the other. While in VisualStudio double click the project and it should open the .csproj file. (If you are not in VisualStudio Right click edit the .csproj file.) Copy all lines enclosed in a ItemGroup tag which say 'PackageReference' into the 'new' project you copied the models to.

Make sure you also rename all Namespaces of the files you moved so that they match the new library name. Link: [how to change namespace of entire project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302567/how-to-change-namespace-of-entire-project)