# Warning CS0436 suddenly appears when upgrading to VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've just upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015, and a ton of CS0436 warnings have appeared, all seemingly relating to the same issue.

I am slowly migrating web applications from VB to C#, so perhaps this is something really simple.  I'm new to C# so please use layman-type answers...

My solution is structured as such:

### Project 1 - Reusable methods (database access, etc)

**\CommonDataAccessFunctionality.vb**

```
Namespace MyCompany
    Public Class CommonDataAccessFunctionality
        Public Sub New(ByVal storedProcedureToRun As String)
            ' db stuff here '
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

### Project 2 - Web Applicable (C#) with dependency on Project 1

**App_Code\DataAccess.cs**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace QrCodes.App_Data
{
    public abstract class QrDataCommon : MyCompany.CommonDataAccessFunctionality
    {
        public QrDataCommon(string storedProcedureToRun)
            : base(storedProcedureToRun)
        {

        }
    }

    public class QrDataGrabber : QrDataCommon
    {
        public QrDataGrabber(string storedProcedureToRun)
            : base(storedProcedureToRun)
        {
    }
    }
}
```

The error is shown on this line:

```
public class QrDataGrabber : QrDataCommon
```

> Warning   CS0436
>   The type 'QrDataCommon' in 'D:\Web\wwwroot\MyApp\MyApp-InProgress-Person
>   WebApi\QrCodes\App_Code\DataAccess.cs'  conflicts with the imported
>   type 'QrDataCommon' in  'QrCodes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 
>   'D:\Web\wwwroot\MyApp\MyApp-InProgress-Person
>   WebApi\QrCodes\App_Code\DataAccess.cs'.

I've read many posts on here about a project referencing itself, however, there are no references in the project dialog (that are listed), only a single dependency in Project 2 to Project 1.  Also, Project 2 has no controls, etc, that reference anything else.

Can anyone please give me some guidance?  I'm not sure if its helpful, but in the object browser when searching for 'QrDataCommon' I see this:

[image]

### Update based on help so far

If I opt to view all files within Solution Explorer, within the \bin\ directory there is a file called QrCodes.dll that gets created when the project/solution is built.  I also see the same in the hidden Debug folder.

If I rename the `QrDataCommon` class to something totally unique, say `QrDataCommonTest123`, and clean/rebuild, the error immediately updates to use the new class name.

Therefore, might this be something to do with the application build target location or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning CS0436
>   The type 'QrDataCommon' in '...DataAccess.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'QrDataCommon' in '...'. Using the type defined in '...DataAccess.cs'.

*Most* people likely run into this because of projects referencing themselves (as you pointed out); however, in your case it's because your VB project has a type with exactly the same **namespace and name** - a result of doing a direct 1:1 port from VB to C#.

Due to the name and namespace being identical C# has a choice to make: which one should it use? It is informing you that it is made the most logical choice and has chosen the one in your C# project - which is probably what you wanted it to do anyway.

These are your options:

- Good option: Once you have completed porting a type to C# delete it from the VB project and recompile the VB project.
- Good option: If you are not distributing your code as a standalone re-usable DLL (it looks like you are not), [change the root namespace of your C# code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871314/change-project-namespace-in-visual-studio)
- Ignore the error until you have completed the port.
- Worst option: Use a [global namespace alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx).

Comment: I changed the default namespace, but the warnings persist.  Sorry if I'm being thick, but `QrDataCommon` is not defined *anywhere* but in Project 2 as shown, so I cannot work out where this conflict is being caused.

Comment: @EvilDr Oh I missed that - I'm being the thick one here. Check *all* `web.config`s in your project (it looks like ASP.Net MVC?) for a cyclic reference.

Comment: @EvilDr If your project references (references node under the project) doesn't have the cycle then it simply has to be in a webconfig. Press CTRL+SHIFT+F, select "Entire Solution" from the dropdown and search for "QrCodes". If that gives too many results try "QrCodes," instead (notice the comma).

Comment: Sorry, @EvilDr I'm really out of ideas. One last thing you could try is recreate your project by copying the code/markup into a new one.

Comment: Sorry @EvilDr, I'm really out of ideas beyond recreating the project.

Comment: Finally found the answer.  It was because App_Code dynamically compiles a code-time, so there *were* two versions always being generated.  Renaming App_Code to something else fixed it.  Marking as the answer because you *were* correct; I just couldn't find the source.  Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 DLLs using the same class name `QrDataCommon`.  Rename one of them or don't reference `QrCodes.dll`.

Comment: Thanks, and again I am probably missing something simple, but `QrDataCommon` is not defined anywhere in the solution apart from in Project 2 as shown

Comment: Found the answer, it was because App_Code was called *App_Code*, which dynamically compiles.  Renaming to AppWideCode fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@EvilDr has the answer but its buried in the comments for the other two answers so I wanted to make it more visible.  The issue is the name of the folder in your project: App_Code.  Anything in a directory with that name is automatically dynamically compiled.  Rename that directory and the problem will go away.