# How to get Visual Studio to use the default namespace when creating a new class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new class in a sub folder in my project, by default it uses DefaultNameSpace.SubFolder.

Anyway to make it just use the default namespace defined at the project level?

Comment: Possibly this is already addressed here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871314/change-project-namespace-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new template for `Class`.  You can use the existing template and just remove the extra "fluff" on the namespace.

See this answer: [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

The specific file to modify for your version of Visual Studio is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

You may want to make a copy of that structure and give your template a different name so you don't end up breaking the default template if you ever want to go back to it.

**Edit**

Looking at the tokens now, I don't see one specifically for the `Default Namespace`, `$safeprojectname$` is probably as close as you get get using tokens, or just hard code it for your specific template.  This is what the template would look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $safeprojectname$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

You can find the predefined tokens here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

Comment: This MSDN link will guide you through exporting an existing template, modifying it, and using it in VS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx

Comment: As of VS 2022, there is now a replaceable parameter named, '$defaultnamespace$' which is what you want. Despite the information on MSDN (in several places) '$safeprojectname$' no longer seems to be available for item templates.