# Copying a project in a solution and updating namespaces - Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

I’m trying to copy an entire project within a solution (let’s call it project A) in visual studio and update the namespace of all classes contained within the copied project.

I can successfully copy the project but I’m not able to update the namespace of all the classes in one operation.

Here’s what I’ve tried:

-Ensuring that VS is closed, navigate to the solution in the file explorer. Make a copy of the project A folder and paste it into the solution.

-Rename project A-copy to Project B.

-Navigate to the csproj file in project B

-Open the solution in VS > select Add existing project > select the csproj file for project B

-With project B displayed in the solution explorer, right click on properties for project B and open.

-At this point the assembly name and the Default namespace are the same as project A.

-I’ve Updated both fields with New values and also updated the assembly information name.

-After building the project and opening any of the class files. The name space on all class files is still the same as project A

Does anyone know how I can update the name space on all class files in a single action, without having to manually update the namespace in each file?

Also tried restarting VS but this did not have any effect.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Project Namespace in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871314/change-project-namespace-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- Find : Oldnamespace
- Replace :Newnamespace
- Select **Entire Solution**
- List item

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is already addressed in older posts. I doubt there is no single method to resolve this. 
1) You can use `Ctrl + H` to replace the old namespace with new one.
2) Press F2 to rename the namespace, hope this replaces the old one.